# Propose renaming uidynamics tag to be uikit-dynamics

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

There is currently a Stack Overflow tag [uidynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uidynamics) which is being used for "UIKit Dynamics" related questions. There is no such thing as `UIDynamics` (though there is a `UIDynamicsAnimator` class and a `UIDynamicItem` protocol).

I would suggest renaming this tag to be [uikit-dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uikit-dynamics). The correct name, "UIKit Dynamics" is illustrated by Apple's WWDC 2013 videos [Getting Started with UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=206) and [Advanced Techniques with UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=221) in which they introduced this new technology.

I would, though, suggest [uidynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uidynamics) as a synonym for the new [uikit-dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uikit-dynamics) tag.

---

#### Update

Since I posted this request, it looks like a new [uikit-dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uikit-dynamics) tag has been added. So, it's now even worse, with two separate tags covering the same topic. I'd suggest consolidating these two tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been completed.  [uidynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uidynamics) is a now a synonym of [uikit-dynamics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uikit-dynamics).